# How do I use provider to update a parent widget if an action is performed on the child widget?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-provider

I have a friends list screen where each friend row is defined by `friendRow.dart`. I made it so that the `friendRow` class has only 3 things: an icon, a username, and an ellipses button. The ellipses button allows the current user to remove the target friend or block them. When either of these 2 actions are performed, I want to make the parent friends list screen requery the current list of friends from Firestore. Using [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider), how do I pass up the knowledge that the parent must be refreshed from the child widget?

The alternate way I could do this would be to code the ellipses button to live on the parent widget instead of the child, but this feels like a counter-intuitive way to solve the problem.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../../services/database.dart';

enum MoreOptions {RemoveFriend, Block}

class FriendRow extends StatefulWidget {
  const FriendRow({
    Key? key,
    required this.friendUsername,
    required this.friendUID
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String friendUsername;
  final String friendUID;

  @override
  State<FriendRow> createState() => _FriendRowState();
}

class _FriendRowState extends State<FriendRow> {
  final database = Database();

  //Writing "Future" alone means Future<dynamic>
  Future _moreOptionsDialog (BuildContext context, MoreOptions selectedItem) {
    String dialogTitle = '';

    if (selectedItem == MoreOptions.RemoveFriend) {
      dialogTitle = 'Remove Friend';
    }

    if (selectedItem == MoreOptions.Block) {
      dialogTitle = 'Block';
    }

    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text(dialogTitle),
            actions: [
              TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (selectedItem == MoreOptions.RemoveFriend) {
                      database.removeFriend(widget.friendUID);
                    }
                    if (selectedItem == MoreOptions.Block) {
                      database.blockFriend(widget.friendUID);
                    }
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                  child: Text('OK')),
              TextButton(onPressed: () {Navigator.of(context).pop();}, child: Text('Cancel')),
            ],
          );
        }
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(flex: 2, child: Image(image: AssetImage('assets/images/userPicture.png')),),
        Expanded(flex: 8, child: Text('USERNAME'),),
        Expanded(flex: 1,
          child:
            PopupMenuButton<MoreOptions>(
              onSelected: (MoreOptions selectedItem) {
                _moreOptionsDialog(context, selectedItem);
              },
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => <PopupMenuEntry<MoreOptions>>[
                const PopupMenuItem<MoreOptions>(
                  value: MoreOptions.RemoveFriend,
                  child: Text('Remove Friend'),
                ),
                const PopupMenuItem<MoreOptions>(
                  value: MoreOptions.Block,
                  child: Text('Block'),
                ),
              ],
            )
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically the soultion in your case is you should use a common state management approaches, like getx, provider ,Bloc or something like this,
if you want basic solution you could pass "onDelete" function to your child widget, this function contains your "UI" logic of removing this widget from the list.

Comment: How would I do this using provider?